# Add custom data with order email content magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email

I want to add custom data in order confirmation email. I have vehicle information that are attached to the order email to show to customer their vehicle make, model, year. These values are attached with `order_id`.

Comment: This book explains it very well: https://shop.vinaikopp.com/grokking-magento/

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara what you want from me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First copy `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php`

Now you have to create function for your requirement.
If your order data return value for vehicle model as `$order['vehicle_model']` then you have to declare function in `Order.php` file of local.

```
public function getVehicleModel(){
    return $this->getVehicleModel();
}
```

You have to set value in System -> Transactional email -> New order template.

```
You have to set below statement in your email template.
{{var order.getVehicleModel()}}
```

Now email template will display vehicle model value.

Same as above you have to generate function for Vehicle year, Vehicle make and call in email template file in admin.

Comment: now i am getting blank email

Comment: plz give me your order collection data related to your vehilcle info field.Then i can tell you about which method and getting parameter for that to available in email.

Comment: my mistake the field name was not correct . +1