# Email In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, coupon-codes

I want to send vaoucher or special number in order email if customer purchase bundle product how i can achieve this

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried, and maybe point out a specific problem that you have?

Comment: i want that if any user purhcase product which type is bundle so i want to send him a code via email is it possible if i do this in order mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this via order email. Here I have made changes in core files. But it would be best if you do this in your own files. These changes are not tested, but will give you an idea of work.

First add **voucher or special number** to head of table in your order email
at

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml

Like

```
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
            <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Vaoucher No#') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

And then modify the following file

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$voucherNo = "";
if ($product->getTypeId() === 'bundle') {
    // Something…
    //$voucherNo = $product->getVoucherNo();
    $voucherNo = "12345_abc";
}
?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                        <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) : ?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceExclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal() + $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount() + $_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'], true, true); ?></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'], true, true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'], true, true); ?></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <br />
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice() + $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount() + $_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <br /><span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl - $_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'], true, true); ?></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'], true, true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'], true, true); ?></span><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $voucherNo ?></td>
</tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style=" border-bottom:2px solid #CCCCCC; padding:3px 9px;">
            <strong style="color:#444444; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->__('Gift Message') ?></strong>
            <?php echo $this->__('From:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?><br />
            <?php echo $this->__('To:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?><br />
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('Message:'); ?></strong><br /><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/add-custom-data-with-order-email-content-magento).

It's the same principal, you can just adapt Vehicle data into voucher data, and add a condition for bundle purchase.